# Blazor - Bind query strings to a dictionary

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have a page with a table and dynamic filters in it. When a filter changes, I need to redirect to the current page with a new or updated query parameter. For example, if I'm in the `/users` route and the name "John" is being searched, I need to redirect to `/users?name=john`. If I want to see all Johns with application role, I need to redirect to `/users?name=john&hasRole=true` and so on. The reason for this is that a search result must be reproducible by sharing the URL.

I need all query parameters as a `Dictionary<string, string>`. How can I bind all query parameters to a `Dictionary<string, string>` in Blazor WASM?

Answer (score 3):

Chris Sainty has a nice post on [working with query strings in blazor](https://chrissainty.com/working-with-query-strings-in-blazor/) but essentially you'll need the [`NavManager`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-7.0#navigation-history-state) and `Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities` and then you can use the [`ParseQuery`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.webutilities.queryhelpers.parsequery?view=aspnetcore-7.0) method to get a dictionary of the query string params:

```cs
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        var uri = NavManager.ToAbsoluteUri(NavManager.Uri);
        if (QueryHelpers.ParseQuery(uri.Query).TryGetValue("initialCount", out var _initialCount))
        {
            currentCount = Convert.ToInt32(_initialCount);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to run the code in `OnParametersSet` because the question says "Redirect to the current page": in such cases `OnInitialized` doesn't get called.

Answer (score 0):

If you know what filters you are applying, you define the query parameters as component parameters (using Brandon's counter example in the other answer).

```cs
@page "/counter"
@inject NavigationManager NavManager

<PageTitle>Counter</PageTitle>

<h1>Counter</h1>

<p role="status">Current count: @CurrentCount</p>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="() => IncrementCount(1)">Increment</button>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="() => IncrementCount(50)">Count plus 50</button>

@code {
    [Parameter, SupplyParameterFromQuery] public int CurrentCount { get; set; } = 0;

    private void IncrementCount(int value)
        => NavManager.NavigateTo($"/counter?CurrentCount={CurrentCount + value}");
}
```

Comment: That's exactly the problem, they are dynamic and different for each table. I'm trying to write a dynamic and reusable table with search component.

Comment: I did qualify the answer with an if.  :-) Good luck.